# How to RollBack a transaction of an EntityManager injected by @PersistenceContext?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I am using JPA and i have an abstract class where i inject my entityManager and i have a generic method where i persist my oject to the database and in all my services class extends that abstract class but the issue is: sometimes i have to persist client and client details but if i have an exception in the persist of client , then my program persist client details that's why i look for a rollBack to call when i have a persist exception.

I khow that i can do like `entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();` but if i manage my entity manager but in my case , it managed by the container.

Here is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityFactory<E>{
protected static final transient Logger LOGGER = CommonLogger.getLogger(AbstractEntityFactory.class);
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Test_PU")
@Transient
@XmlTransient
private transient EntityManager entityManager;

public E persist(final E arg0) {
    LOGGER.debug("persist : Begin");
    this.getEntityManager().persist(arg0);
    this.getEntityManager().flush();
    LOGGER.debug("persist : End");
    return arg0;        
}
```

}

NB: i have Jboss EAP6 as server

Comment: Is it Spring which is injecting the EntityManager? But then, just throwing the `RuntimeException` should rollback the transaction. Is it not happening?

Comment: Any container will rollback the transaction when there is an exception, and most persistence providers are required by JPA to mark the transaction for rollback when a persistence exception occurs.  Can you detail more about what problem you are looking to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UserTransaction.rollback to roll back the current transaction.

Comment: i don't do no transaction begin no transaction end and no comit because is the container do this and  as you see above i inject the entityManager by @PersistenceContext

Answer (score 0):

Since your using a "container". I assume you mean something like wildfly,..
In that case I assume your using @Transactional somewhere. This annotation has an attribute called rollbackFor.

If I remember correctly the default setup does not rollback for RuntimeExceptions. So you might wana change this.

If you need to rollback manually use the UserTransaction. You should be able to get it via

```
public class SomeBean {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction transaction;
}
```

Comment: i don't use UserTransaction any where

Comment: But you have to when you want to control the transaction.

Comment: I do one think is juste injecting the entityManager via `@PersistenceContext` the as you see in my method i persiste my object then i make a flush that all what i do, and in my persistence.xml i have : `transaction-type="JTA"`

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use transaction rollback support annotation :

`    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public E persist(final E arg0) {
    LOGGER.debug("persist : Begin");
    this.getEntityManager().persist(arg0);
    this.getEntityManager().flush();
    LOGGER.debug("persist : End");
    return arg0;        
}`
```

Comment: `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)` is for Spring ? because i don't use it and i use JPA and EJB and CDI